# How to define an n-variate empirical distribution function probability for any n?

Tags: function-construction, probability-or-statistics

I'm using Mathematica 9.0 to calculate the probability according to the empirical distribution function (EDF) of some sample data. Afterwords this is included in a maximization stage so I define this probability as a function. I have to do apply this to groups of data in which each group has different dimensionality. Therefore I'd like to define a generic version of "probability given by an EDF" that I can apply to any of these groups.

Here there is a toy example for some 2-dimensional samples:

```
data = Transpose[{{1, 3, 4, 9, 8, 7, 8}, {2, 1, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9}}];
MatrixForm[data]
```

Its EDF is simply:

```
edf := EmpiricalDistribution[data];
```

Then by hand one can easily define its probability function:

```
 edfProbFunction[t1_, t2_] := NProbability[x1 <= t1 \[And] x2 <= t2, {x1, x2} \[Distributed] edf];
```

and compute the probability by just defining:

```
edfProb[w1_, w2_] := Evaluate[edfProbFunction[w1, w2]];
```

In this way, given a new point (2,4) from this distribution, it has probability 0.142857 given by:

```
edfProb[2,4]
```

My question is **how to define a function like *edfProbFunction* for any dimension, not a fixed dimension** (2 in the example)?

I tried to do it in different ways but didn't succeed. I lack background in Mathematica so these attempts may be nonesense. I summarize them anyway in case this can be of any help:

**First naive attempt** -- use a vector of input variables, straightforward

```
edfProbFunction[t__] := NProbability[x <= t, x \[Distributed] edf];
edfProb[w__] := Evaluate[edfProbFunction[w]];
```

Using this definition of *edfProb* together with the *edfProbFunction* defined in the toy example works, but not with this *edfProbFunction* here. This made me think that I had to somehow made explicit each of the individual predicates (the inequalities) in *edfProbFunction*

**Second attempt** -- use MakeBoxes

But a simple example shows that the expressions produced by this are not seen as variables in *edfProbFunction*:

```
xP /: MakeBoxes[xP[x___], form_] := RowBox[Riffle[Map[MakeBoxes[#, form] &, {x}], ","]]
x[1] = "" <> {"x", IntegerString[1]};
x[2] = "" <> {"x", IntegerString[2]};
varx = xP[x[1],x[2]] (*this produces a list x1,x2 *)
edfProbFunction[t1_,t2_] := NProbability[x1 <= t1 \[And] x2 <= t2, {varx} \[Distributed] edf];
```

**Third attempt** -- I tried to define a function that recursively creates the predicate, but it doesn't work neither:

```
table = Table[x[i] <= t[i], {i, 2}];
g[n_] := If[Length[n] > 1, n[[1]] \[And] g[Drop[n, 1]], If[Length[n] == 1, n[[1]], 0]]
predicate = g[table]
edfProbFunction[t_] := NProbability[predicate, {t[1], t[2]} \[Distributed] edf];
edfProb[w__] := Evaluate[edfProbFunction[w]];
edfProb[{2, 4}]
```

Any suggestions will be welcome, specially complete answers to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest issue in trying to put this together is that `NProbability` mixed with `EmpiricalDistribution` doesn't seem to like array indexed variables. Building up symbols programatically seems to fix the issue.

```
edfP[data_?MatrixQ][t__?NumericQ] /; 
  Length[{t}] == Length[data[[1]]] := Block[{vars, x},
  vars = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, Length[{t}]}]; 
  NProbability @@ {And @@ Thread[vars <= {t}], 
    vars \[Distributed] EmpiricalDistribution[data]}
  ]
```

First lets verify it works for your example...

```
edfProb[3, 4]
(* 0.285714 *)

edfP[data][3, 4]
(* 0.285714 *)
```

And now to generalize...

```
edfP[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {10^4, 4}]][-1, 1, 2, 1]

(* 0.1061 *)
```

Note that if you are going to run this repeatedly for the same data you should evaluate the empirical distribution outside and pass that in rather than the data itself.

**EDIT:**

Now all that said, this seems like overkill to me. If I understand your question correctly why can't you just use `CDF`?

```
SeedRandom[1];
dat = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {10^4, 4}];

edfP[dat][-1, 1, 2, 1]
(* 0.1143 *)

CDF[EmpiricalDistribution@dat, {-1, 1, 2, 1}]
(* 0.1143 *)
```

Comment: Both your approaches work really fine, they answer my question. So why can't I just use CDF? Well, I couldn't because I didn't even know this simple way, but now I can. Thanks a lot!