# Custom multivariate discrete distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

*This is related to [How to define an n-variate empirical distribution function probability for any n?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43135/how-to-define-an-n-variate-empirical-distribution-function-probability-for-any-n)
and 
[RandomVariate from 2-dimensional probability distribution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2635/randomvariate-from-2-dimensional-probability-distribution) 
but I don't think neither questions (and their answers) answer the question below. (The first one constructs the problem from data and not from a priori specified probability weights, and hence they can use `NProbability`; and the second one seems like an extreme overkill for something like a simple discrete distribution where one doesn't really need to kick out random number generators).*

I want to construct a multivariate discrete distribution so that I can use the full functionality of `RandomVariate` and things of that sort.

In 1-dimension, I can use `EmpiricalDistribution`. For instance, for a $X \sim Bernoulli(p)$ with $p = 1/2$, it is simply

```
gdist = EmpiricalDistribution[{0.5, 0.5} -> {0, 1}]
```

and from this, I can go on to compute mean and variances via `Expectation`, say

```
Expectation[ 2*x + 1, x \[Distributed] gdist]
```

as afforded by `RandomVariate` and all its friends.

**Question:** How does one do that for a *multivariate* discrete distribution (whether via `EmpiricalDistribution` or not)? That is, suppose we consider,

$$
(X,Y) = 
\begin{equation} 
\begin{cases} 
 (1,0), \quad \text{with probability } p_{10} \\ 
 (0,1), \quad p_{01} \\ 
 (0,0), \quad p_{00} \\ 
 (1,1), \quad p_{11}. 
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}, 
$$
where of course $p_{10} + p_{01} + p_{00} + p_{11} = 1$ are the probability weights. How does one implement the above distribution, say labelled as `gmultdist` so that we can compute `Expectation[ 2*x + 3*y, {x,y} \[Distributed] gmultdist]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weghts do not have to be equal or even numerical.

```
$Version

(* "10.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)" *)

Format[p[x_, y_]] := Subscript[p, Row[{x, y}]]

assume = {Thread[0 <= {p[0, 0], p[0, 1], p[1, 0], p[1, 1]} <= 1], 
    p[0, 0] + p[0, 1] + p[1, 0] + p[1, 1] == 1} // Flatten;

gmultdist = 
  EmpiricalDistribution[{p[0, 0], p[0, 1], p[1, 0], 
     p[1, 1]} -> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}];
```

Using a replacement rule for the total probability gives the expected form of the result.

```
PDF[gmultdist, #] & /@ {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}} /. 
 p[0, 0] + p[0, 1] + p[1, 0] + p[1, 1] -> 1
```

[image]

However, using assumptions gives the result in terms of three independent variables rather than the shorter form wth four variables.

```
Assuming[assume, (PDF[gmultdist, #] & /@ {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}) // 
  Simplify]
```

[image]

```
Assuming[assume, (Probability[
      x == #[[1]] && y == #[[2]], {x, y} \[Distributed] gmultdist] & /@ {{0, 
      0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}) // Simplify]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a better solution than mine :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd subsequently realized that I could simply just do

```
gmultdist = EmpiricalDistribution[  {0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25} -> { {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}  } ]
```

for the case of all equal weights. My original mistake was in "flipping" the order of `->` initially in `EmpiricalDistribution`.